# Dealing with VBA Automation when searched values is not found

Tags: excel, vba

Using code provided in another post, I have slightly amended this to create a macro which looks up phrases searches for these using an online database (JECFA) to return a corresponding phrase (ADI) in the adjacent cell as shown below:

[image]

The code for this is:

```
Sub getADI()

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("b3").Select

Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
    Call GetContent
Loop

End Sub


Public Sub GetContent()


    Const Url = "https://apps.who.int/food-additives-contaminants-jecfa-database/Search.aspx"
    Dim oHttp As Object, oHtml As HTMLDocument, MyDict As Object
    Dim DictKey As Variant, payload$, searchKeyword$
    
    Set oHtml = New HTMLDocument
    Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set MyDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
1
    'send get requests first to parse the value of "__VIEWSTATE", "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" e.t.c., as in oHtml.getElementById("__VIEWSTATE").Value
    
    With oHttp
        .Open "GET", Url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        oHtml.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    searchKeyword = Selection.Value 'this is the search keyword you wanna use from your predefined search terms
    
    'MyDict stores keys and values within dictionary, as in __VIEWSTATE = "some string" and so on
    
    MyDict("__VIEWSTATE") = oHtml.getElementById("__VIEWSTATE").Value
    MyDict("__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR") = oHtml.getElementById("__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR").Value
    MyDict("__EVENTVALIDATION") = oHtml.getElementById("__EVENTVALIDATION").Value
    MyDict("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtSearch") = searchKeyword
    MyDict("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSearch") = "Search"
    MyDict("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtSearchFEMA") = ""

    'converting keys and values to a string joined with ampersand so that you can use it as a parameter while issuing post requests, which is what payload is doing
    
    payload = ""
    For Each DictKey In MyDict
        payload = IIf(Len(DictKey) = 0, WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(DictKey) & "=" & WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(MyDict(DictKey)), _
        payload & "&" & WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(DictKey) & "=" & WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(MyDict(DictKey)))
    Next DictKey
    
    With oHttp
        .Open "POST", Url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .send (payload)
        oHtml.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = oHtml.querySelector("#SearchResultItem > a").NextSibling.NodeValue

On Error Resume Next
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select



 
End Sub
```

This works well however I now wish to implement some sort of failsafe in case the phrase is not found.

So far I have just tried to implement `On Error Resume Next` at the end of Public Sub GetContent() however testing this with a made up phrase just returns an error regardless.

Ideally I wish to implement a phrase saying something like "Not found" but skipping to the next line regardless could also work.

Comment: What does the html look like if you get a valid respond vs nothing found? Is there anything that says "nothing found" then you could create an if on that sentence in the html.

Comment: I'm confused, your On Error Resume Next is only catching errors from the line `ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select`, after that you hit `End Sub` so nothing else is covered by your error handler. If your HTTP request raises an error on an invalid phrase then you can use On Error Resume Next before the request and check if Err.Number <> 0 (indicating an error was raised and suppressed, so return "Not Found"). If as @Andreas points out the http request succeeds but returns some HTML that looks different, then you can detect that and return Not Found

Comment: I guess `oHtml.querySelector("#SearchResultItem > a").NextSibling.NodeValue` may throw an error if the item does not exist, so use OnErrorResumeNext (OERN) just before there and afterwards if Err.Number <> 0 there was an error and you know the html selector failed. Make sense?

Comment: Hi thanks for replying! I wont lie I am quite new to VBA and the code above was provided to me on another post so please bear with me when looking at your suggestions. As for the html, I don't believe that it changes if a phrase is not found. The page just returns as normal but where results are normally populated nothing is returned. Annoyingly the website is currently down (https://apps.who.int/food-additives-contaminants-jecfa-database/Error.aspx) and so I will test out your suggestions soon once its back up.

Comment: I also believe what Greedo says is correct that the queryselector fails because it's not there. So most likely the on error resume next should be above the queryselector. Then you could `if ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" then ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Nothing found"`. But it's better and nicer to capture the error before we place something on the sheet.

Comment: On Error Resume Next
    
`ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = oHtml.querySelector("#SearchResultItem > a").NextSibling.NodeValue`
`If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Nothing found"` appears to work well. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use error handling when you can just test the return value of the function. If the function `oHtml.querySelector("#SearchResultItem > a")` returns Nothing if the value is not found, then test for that.

```
Set item = oHtml.querySelector("#SearchResultItem > a")
if item is Nothing then
    ' item not found
    ' maybe write log message and exit function?
else
    Set item = item.NextSibling
    if item is Nothing then
        ' no next sibling
        ' maybe write log message and exit function?
    else
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = item.NodeValue
    end if
end if
```